# Django loaddata with natural keys and many-to-many-relation to self

Tags: python, django

I have a model with `ManyToManyField` to `"self"`. Now I want to copy data from my local to the production environment. In order to do that, I'd like to dump all entries from my database to a fixture and load that on the production server. Because that server already contains data, I export them using natural keys. The export runs fine, but I get errors during `loaddata` if one instance references a relation to another instance of the same model that is defined below that one in the fixture.

What confuses me: Everything goes well, if I don't use natural keys. But this clashes with data already present on production.

Please consider the following example:

```
from django.db import models


class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, name):
        return self.get(name=name)


class Person(models.Model):
    objects = PersonManager()

    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField("self", blank=True)

    def natural_key(self):
        return self.name,
```

To reproduce:

```
>>> python manage.py shell
>>> from relations.models import *
>>> person1 = Person.objects.create(name='foo')
>>> person2 = Person.objects.create(name='bar')
>>> person3 = Person.objects.create(name='baz')
>>> person2.friends.add(person2)
>>> person2.save()
>>> exit()
>>>
>>> python manage.py dumpdata relations.Person --natural-primary --natural-foreign > relations/fixtures/people.json

# change the database url to an empty database and run migrations

>>> python3 manage.py loaddata people
raises relations.models.DoesNotExist: Person matching query does not exist.
```

If I omit the `--natural-primary` and `-natural-foreign` but follow the same steps, loading into a fresh db works.

Can somebody explain why the different behaviour occurs?